# Fast column shuffle of each row numpy

Tags: python, random, numpy, vectorization

I have a large 10,000,000+ length array that contains rows. I need to individually shuffle those rows. For example:

```
[[1,2,3]
 [1,2,3]
 [1,2,3]
 ...
 [1,2,3]]
```

to

```
[[3,1,2]
 [2,1,3]
 [1,3,2]
 ...
 [1,2,3]]
```

I'm currently using

```
map(numpy.random.shuffle, array)
```

But it's a python (not NumPy) loop and it's taking 99% of my execution time. Sadly, the PyPy JIT doesn't implement `numpypy.random`, so I'm out of luck. Is there any faster way? I'm willing to use any library (`pandas`, `scikit-learn`, `scipy`, `theano`, etc. as long as it uses a Numpy `ndarray` or a derivative.)

If not, I suppose I'll resort to Cython or C++.

Comment: `numpy.apply_along_axis(numpy.random.shuffle, 1, array)` might be a bit faster. I haven't timed it.

Comment: It's actually a good deal (≈10x) slower because it requires a memory-copy (`shuffle` is in place, so you need to use `permutation` instead).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

```
In [10]: a=np.zeros(shape=(1000,3))

In [12]: a[:,0]=1

In [13]: a[:,1]=2

In [14]: a[:,2]=3

In [17]: %timeit map(np.random.shuffle, a)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.65 ms per loop

In [21]: all_perm=np.array((list(itertools.permutations([0,1,2]))))

In [22]: b=all_perm[np.random.randint(0,6,size=1000)]

In [25]: %timeit (a.flatten()[(b+3*np.arange(1000)[...,np.newaxis]).flatten()]).reshape(a.shape)
1000 loops, best of 3: 393 us per loop
```

If there are only a few columns, then the number of all possible permutation is much smaller than the number of rows in the array (in this case, when there are only 3 columns, there are only 6 possible permutations). A way to make it faster is to make all the permutations at once first and then rearrange each row by randomly picking one permutation from all possible permutations.

It still appears to be 10 times faster even with larger dimension:

```
#adjust a accordingly
In [32]: b=all_perm[np.random.randint(0,6,size=1000000)]

In [33]: %timeit (a.flatten()[(b+3*np.arange(1000000)[...,np.newaxis]).flatten()]).reshape(a.shape)
1 loops, best of 3: 348 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit map(np.random.shuffle, a)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.64 s per loop
```

Comment: Nice. This is faster than my method.

Comment: @unutbu, I was inspired by yours `perms=`..., must confess, I have MKL on my machine so maybe that make it even slightly faster. On yours it is about 6 fold.

Comment: Nice! Making the computer do less work is always better since every implementation wins. @CT Zhu, I get ≈12x on the fedora BLAS, so it's completely reasonable.

Comment: None of this is using BLAS. Random numbers are handled by NumPy's fork of randomkit.

Comment: I suspected that. Nothing that I'm doing specifically requires BLAS routines. However, just to be sure. (Since I don't really know).

Comment: python 3 update: `map` has to be enclosed in `list` because it is a lazy generator and won't be effectuated otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

If the permutations of the columns are enumerable, then you could do this:

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np

def using_perms(array):
    nrows, ncols = array.shape
    perms = np.array(list(IT.permutations(range(ncols))))
    choices = np.random.randint(len(perms), size=nrows)
    i = np.arange(nrows).reshape(-1, 1)
    return array[i, perms[choices]]

N = 10**7
array = np.tile(np.arange(1,4), (N,1))
print(using_perms(array))
```

yields (something like)

```
[[3 2 1]
 [3 1 2]
 [2 3 1]
 [1 2 3]
 [3 1 2]
 ...
 [1 3 2]
 [3 1 2]
 [3 2 1]
 [2 1 3]
 [1 3 2]]
```

Here is a benchmark comparing it to

```
def using_shuffle(array):
    map(numpy.random.shuffle, array)
    return array

In [151]: %timeit using_shuffle(array)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.17 s per loop

In [152]: %timeit using_perms(array)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.78 s per loop
```

---

Edit: CT Zhu's method is faster than mine:

```
def using_Zhu(array):
    nrows, ncols = array.shape    
    all_perm = np.array((list(itertools.permutations(range(ncols)))))
    b = all_perm[np.random.randint(0, all_perm.shape[0], size=nrows)]
    return (array.flatten()[(b+3*np.arange(nrows)[...,np.newaxis]).flatten()]
            ).reshape(array.shape)

In [177]: %timeit using_Zhu(array)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.7 s per loop
```

Here is a slight variation of Zhu's method which may be even a bit faster:

```
def using_Zhu2(array):
    nrows, ncols = array.shape    
    all_perm = np.array((list(itertools.permutations(range(ncols)))))
    b = all_perm[np.random.randint(0, all_perm.shape[0], size=nrows)]
    return array.take((b+3*np.arange(nrows)[...,np.newaxis]).ravel()).reshape(array.shape)

In [201]: %timeit using_Zhu2(array)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.46 s per loop
```

Comment: Your answer takes huge amount of time and ram, `np.array(list(IT.permutations(range(ncols))))` crashed my program when I did it for my machine learning algorithm

Comment: Using `np.array(list(itertools.permutations(range(ncols))))` will generate all permutations in factorial time, so it is not feasible for arrays with large `ncols`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df = df.apply(lambda x:np.random.shuffle(x) or x, axis=1)
```

And then extract the numpy array from the dataframe

```
print df.values
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's ≈70x slower. I suspect that pandas is adding more overhead, and that a memory-copy is occurring (possibly two). That `or` trick, though, is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have an alternate, equivalent strategy, building upon the previous answers:

```
# original sequence
a0 = np.arange(3) + 1

# length of original sequence
L = a0.shape[0]

# number of random samples/shuffles
N_samp = 1e4

# from above
all_perm = np.array( (list(itertools.permutations(np.arange(L)))) )
b = all_perm[np.random.randint(0, len(all_perm), size=N_samp)]

# index a with b for each row of b and collapse down to expected dimension
a_samp = a0[np.newaxis, b][0]
```

I'm not sure how this compares performance-wise, but I like it for its readability.